# Append an element to my array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, append

I want to append an element to my array, how can I achieve that?

(The alert window displays '1' no matter how many times I click the button)

**html**:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js" ></script>
   <button type="submit" onclick="btnClick()">Click</button>

  <form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**javascript**:

```
var myArray = [];

function btnClick()
{
    myArray.push("some value");
    alert(myArray.length);
}
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Turns out I'm really stupid. Clicking the button also reloads the javascript.

Comment: i missed that as i made the code more general to post here

Comment: try creating a fiddle

Comment: This should return `undefined` every time. There must be something else going on in the code you didn't post that's causing the behavior you described.

Comment: @ScottSchupbach I messed up when i made my question "forum-friendly", sorry about that, i've edited it and now it returns 1 all the time, what am i missing? thanks

Comment: @ScottSchupbach you were right! The code i was using for calling the function also reloaded the javascript... me such newb. Thank you for taking your time anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line with alert to

```
alert(myArray[myArray.length - 1]);
```

for the last element of the array.

Comment: thank you for answering, but that just gives me 0 instead of 1, its not actually increasing in length for every time the function is called?

Comment: it actually gives me undefined

Answer (score -2):

```
myArray[] = "You now added this new element to your array!";
```

Or if you want it want to edit one:

```
myArray[3] = "Fourth element is now this string"
```

Comment: Oops my mistake, wasn't paying attention, thought it was php